# How do I access a label to change its text in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to change the Label's text, but I have no idea how to access it. I have added the label and a button and I want to change the label's text on button click. However, I cannot access the label from the function - see the line with the question marks. What should I change it to?

When I try the code as is I get "Example instance has no attribute 'frame2'"

I am using Python 2.7

============== update =========

changed frame2 to self.frame2, but it did not solve the problem

```
class Example(Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.all = []
      self.path = ""
      self.parent = parent
      self.initUI()

   def initUI(self):

    self.parent.title("SomeName")
    self.style = Style()
    self.style.theme_use("default")

    self.frame2 = Frame(self, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=2)
    self.frame2.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=False)

    # this is my label
    usrLable = Label(self.frame2, text="Username: ") 
    usrLable.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=1)

    frame6 = Frame(self, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=2)
    frame6.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    # this is my button
    stopButton = Button(frame6, text="Stop", command=self.stopButtonClick)
    stopButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def stopButtonClick(self):
        try:
           self.frame2.usrLable.configure(text="hello") # ?????????????
        except Exception,e:
              print str(e)
        return
```

Comment: frame2` is a local variable. `self.frame2` is an instance variable. You need to consistently use instance variables if you expect to use a variable in more than one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the following line:

```
frame2 = Frame(self, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=2)
frame2.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=False)
```

with:

```
self.frame2 = Frame(self, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=2)
self.frame2.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=False)
```

to make `frame2` an instance attribute instead of local variable.

And also change the references to `frame2` to `self.frame2` accordingly.

Same for the `usrLable`.

---

```
class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.all = []
        self.path = ""
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("SomeName")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")

        self.frame2 = Frame(self, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=2)
        self.frame2.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=False)

        self.usrLable = Label(self.frame2, text="Username: ") 
        self.usrLable.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=1)

        self.frame6 = Frame(self, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=2)
        self.frame6.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        stopButton = Button(self.frame6, text="Stop", command=self.stopButtonClick)
        stopButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def stopButtonClick(self):
        self.usrLable.configure(text="hello")
```

Comment: Actually, the label is added to frame2, so that was a typo on my end, but even when I change frame2 to self.frame2, I get an error: Frame instance has no attribute 'usrLable'

Comment: @THTodorov, In the question, you said you've got ` "Example instance has no attribute 'frame6'"` error. Is it also `frame2` ?

Comment: @THTodorov, Could you give the code that can be run? Seeing code in the question only, I can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: Updated the question - it is now frame 2 that gives the error.

Comment: still does not work, I changed frame2 to self.frame2 in both lines

Comment: @THTodorov, I updated the answer to include the whole code. Check it out.

Comment: Great, once I changed the usrLable also to self.usrLable it works just fine. Thank you for your help!